# How can i call a my function in a qtslot?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I'm trying to call my function as a function slot in Qt,But i don't know how to go about it.
it seems the following approach is wrong :

Update:
According to an answer i updated my source code,but still something is apparently wrong with it.Trying to compile this snippet of code causes these errors:

> C2515:' no appropriate default constructor is available.'

And

> C2665: QObject::connect':none of the 3 overloads could convert all the
>   arguments.'

respectively in Visual studio 2010.

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QObject>
#include <QMessageBox>

class myclass;
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc,argv);

    QPushButton btnshowmessage("show");
    myclass *my=new myclass();
    QObject::connect(&btnshowmessage,SIGNAL(clicked()),my,SLOT(warningmessage()));
    btnshowmessage.show();
    return a.exec();
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class myclass: public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:myclass(){}

        public slots:
            void warningmessage()
            {
                QMessageBox::warning(0,"Warning","Test Message!",QMessageBox::Ok);
            }
};
```

Comment: Put the definition of myclass before int main() and see if that fixes things. With the forward declaration connect has no idea that myclass is a QObject derivative.

Comment: @drescherjm:I used a forward declaration to fix that.Even if i do what you told me i get bunch of other linker specific errors! which i have no idea of its cause!

Comment: I am telling you the forward declaration will not work. Also the linker errors are probably caused by moc not running on your code. Remember moc always needs to be run if you have signals / slots in your class or use the Q_OBJECT macro. I am not sure how you are defining your project to invoke moc and I probably can not help with that since I generate my Qt projects for Visual Studio using CMake (which sets up moc for the files I specify) and not the qmake or the qtaddon.

Comment: Are you using the visual studio Qt Add-in and is it set up as a qt project?

Comment: @drescherjm +1 r.e. the fwd declaration - this is simply a c++ error and nothing to do with it being Qt

Comment: @Pete:Yes i am using Qt-Add-in.And yes it is set up as a qt project.

Comment: I believe for the Qt addin you need to add #include "main.moc" to the bottom of your main.cpp

Comment: @drescherjm:No ,I declared the class in a separate file and all went fine without even a warning:)thank you again for your time:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use signals and slots to connect one *Object's* signal to another *Object's* slot. Every signal or slot should be inside a class which must be also derived from `QObject` class and contain the `Q_OBJECT` macro.

So to make your code work, put the slot into some class of yours:

```
class MySlotClass:public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public slots:
void MyFunction()
    {
        QMessageBox::warning(0,"WarningTest","This is a waring text message",QMessageBox::Ok);
    }
}
```

and connect like this:

```
MySlotClass m = new MySlotClass();
Qobject::connect(&btnShowaMessageBox,SIGNAL(clicked()), &m ,SLOT(MyFunction()));
```

Comment: The connect will compile but fail - SLOT(myFunction()) should be SLOT(MyFunction()) (or the function in the class should start with a lowercase letter).  The SLOT macro converts its argument to a string and the lookup is done a runtime.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall:Thank you very much.By the way should it not be :
MySlotClass *m = new MySlotClass();
instead of the 
MySlotClass m = new MySlotClass();

Comment: I still get errors doing that.I updated the first post to address the latest issues.

Comment: @Hossein, put your class in a separate unit. The class definition should be in a header file.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall:Whats the difference?! I should be able to declare a class where ever i wish right?,I have done this and also seen it in lots of C++ books!.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall:I did as told and it compiled just fine:)
Thank you.though i have no idea why it acted like that.

Comment: @Houssein: in main, the compiler had only seen the forward declaration to myclass so far and you were trying to a) create a new object of that class and b) convert it to a QObject*.  At this point the compiler only knew of myclass as an incomplete type.

Answer (score 2):

Currently Qt does not allow connection of signals to functions that are not declared as slots on some QObject derivative.  I believe [Qt5 may offer this possibility](http://woboq.com/blog/new-signals-slots-syntax-in-qt5.html), but connect will have different syntax to allow this.

basically your slot function must be in a QObject derived class and declared in a

```
public slots:
```

section.

Read the [documentation on signals/slots](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/signalsandslots.html).